# addValueEventListener brings anything

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some problem with Firebase method **addValueEventListner().**
My code should bring me user messages from my database and show it in a ListView called *conversa*, but it's not getting anything back.

Debugging the code, it did not enter in **new ValeuEventListener(...)** and **getView()** neither, although getView is working fine.

I made a teste filling the ArrayList with Mensagem local objetcs and it works.

Anyone knows where am I messing up?

The conversation activity:

```
public class ConversaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

<...>

    mensagens = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new MensagemAdapter(
            ConversaActivity.this,
            mensagens);
    conversa.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Buscando todas as mensagens
    firebase = ConfigFirebase.getFirebase();
    firebase.child("mensagem").child(id_remetente).child(id_destinatario);

    //Listener para as mensagens
    valueEventListenerMensagem = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mensagens.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Mensagem mensagem_recuperada = dados.getValue(Mensagem.class);
                mensagens.add(mensagem_recuperada);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    firebase.addValueEventListener(valueEventListenerMensagem);
<...> 
}
```

The messages adapter:

```
public class MensagemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Mensagem> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Mensagem> mensagens;

public MensagemAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Mensagem> objects) {
    super(c, 0, objects);
    this.context = c;
    this.mensagens = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = null;

    if(mensagens != null) {
        Preferencias preferencias = new Preferencias(context);
        String id_remetente = preferencias.getIdentificador();

        //Inicializando metódo que traz o layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        Mensagem mensagem_index = mensagens.get(position);

        if(id_remetente.equals(mensagem_index.getIdUsuario())) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_mensagem_enviada, parent, false);
            TextView textoMensagem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_msg_enviada);
            textoMensagem.setText(mensagem_index.getMensagem());
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_mensagem_recebida, parent, false);
            TextView textoMensagem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_msg_recebidas);
            textoMensagem.setText(mensagem_index.getMensagem());
        }

    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Firebase "mensagens" branchs are like - added with .push():

```
 mensagens
      id_remente
          id_destinatario
                mensagem_object
                mensagem_object
                ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not getting anything back because you are creating and using your `ArrayList` and `MensagemAdapter` outside `onDataChange()` method which means that by the time at their creation you did not finish getting the data from the database. `onDataChange()` method has an asynchronous behaviour which means that is called even before your are trying to add those object of `Mensagem` class to the `mensagens` list. A quick solution would be to declare both, the `ArrayList` and `MensagemAdapter` inside `onDataChange()` method. Also you need to set the adapter inside that method. If you want to use that list outside, you need to create your own callback and for that I recommend you see the last part of my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)**.